# How can I run .NET Core unit tests in Bamboo?

Tags: continuous-integration, .net-core, nunit, bamboo

We have a .NET Core 2.1 unit test project, which contains a battery of NUnit tests. We are using NUnit 3.10.1.

Unfortunately, NUnit Console does not yet support .NET Core projects. So the only way to run tests in Bamboo is to use the `dotnet test` command:

```
dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=testresults.trx"
```

So I tried doing that by running it as a command in the Bamboo build, and it does indeed run, but when it fails, it just says that the step failed, without specifying which tests caused it to fail.

I created a step to parse the test result file, but the build fails before reaching this step. So how should I set this up so that I can see the test results?

I've asked this question over on the community page at [Atlassian](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/How-to-run-NUnit-tests-for-a-NET-Core-project/qaq-p/761638), but I didn't get any useful responses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a workaround. It doesn't feel 100% right, but it seems to do the trick. Any better solutions are welcomed!

1. Make a "command" task to run the `dotnet test` command.
2. Make a "MS Test Parser" task to parse the test results, and (here's the essential part:) **move it under "Final tasks"** so the the parser executes even if the test step fails.

Comment: @Łukasz because when I was using NUnit-Console, the test step was a single task in Bamboo; it runs the tests and parses them in the same step. Here we're separating the steps and running the second step in a "finally" clause, which instinctively just doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Ah, ok, I've never had possibility to have testing and parsing in one tasks.

Comment: I have adopted this solution and the job runs successfully but the passed .NET Core 3.1 tests do not appear in the results afterwards. Does it only show failed tests?